# How to redirect output from Groovy script?

Tags: java, groovy

I wonder if there is any way I could change the default output (System.out) for the groovy script that I'm executing from my Java code.

Here is the Java code:

```
public void exec(File file, OutputStream output) throws Exception {
    GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell();
    shell.evaluate(file);
}
```

And the sample groovy script:

```
def name='World'
println "Hello $name!"
```

Currently the execution of the method, evaluates scripts that writes "Hello World!" to the console (System.out). How can I redirect output to the OutputStream passed as a parameter?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this using [Binding](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Binding.html)

```
public void exec(File file, OutputStream output) throws Exception {
    Binding binding = new Binding()
    binding.setProperty("out", output) 
    GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);
    shell.evaluate(file);
}
```

After comments

```
public void exec(File file, OutputStream output) throws Exception {
    Binding binding = new Binding()
    binding.setProperty("out", new PrintStream(output)) 
    GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);
    shell.evaluate(file);
}
```

Groovy Script

```
def name='World'
out << "Hello $name!"
```

Comment: That would work, but I'd like to redirect *any* output written to the standard output. Especially by built-in functions such us println().

Comment: You were *about* right. The solution is to wrap the output int the java.io.PrintStream and pass as "out" property to the shell!

Comment: yay!, my first bronze badge!
Happy it work it out! How did you wrap the output?

Comment: Congrats! Simply use new PrintStream(output) and pass as "out" property to binding.

Comment: Really? binding.setProperty takes an OutputStream and somehow works without calling .write??

Comment: http://db.tt/5gXLYFYG here is a working example just run in the console >groovy exec.groovy the write is made in out << "Hello $name". I left groovy some time ago. Anyway :)

Comment: @jjchiw could you update your answer with the `PrintStream` as parameter then the answer is correct and no one needs to read the comments.

Comment: You forgot to mention that "println()" will also works. This is the main part of question.

Answer (score 3):

Use [SystemOutputInterceptor](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/ui/SystemOutputInterceptor.html) class. You can start intercepting output before script evaluation and stop after.

```
def output = "";
def interceptor = new SystemOutputInterceptor({ output += it; false});
interceptor.start()
println("Hello")
interceptor.stop()
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using javax.script.ScriptEngine? You can specify its writer.

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("Groovy");
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new StringWriter());
engine.getContext().setWriter(writer);
engine.getContext().setErrorWriter(writer);
engine.eval("println 'HELLO'")
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you could do this quite nicely by overwriting the `println` method in your GroovyShell's metaClass.  The following works in Groovy Console:

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder()

this.metaClass.println = {
    b.append(it)
    System.out.println it
}

println "Hello, world!"
System.out.println b.toString()
```

output:

```
Hello, world!
Hello, world!
```

Answer (score 0):

[System.setOut()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29) is just what you need.

Comment: I'm afraid System.setOut is too heavyweight :) It changes the output globally for the entire JVM and this is not something that I wanted to do :)