# How to redirect ALL output from a groovy script to another stream, without changing the script?

Tags: groovy

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531675/how-to-redirect-output-from-groovy-script), has [an accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1531726/11236) that only redirects the `out` "command" to an output stream. I would like to redirect all the output from a script to a stream, not just a subset of the output that is created with `out << "hello world"` commands.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269814/11236) changes the script to write all its output via `out` "command". Is there a solid solution that does't require changing the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind `System.out` to another stream, like (if you're calling it from plain Java):

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("console.out"));
System.setOut(ps);
//call your script there
```

or more groovier:

```
System.out = new File('console.out').newPrintWriter()
//call your script there
```

Comment: So basically, if I run the script in the same process, I can't redirect only the script's output, but rather I have to do it globally?

Comment: Yes. If it uses global output - you have only one way: redefine this global output. Btw, probably you can make your own implementation of printwriter, that will check caller thread, catch only data for required thread, and send all other output to original out

Comment: that would be interesting. Wrapped in a Java 7 closeable with proper release at the end, this can actually work.